# How can we perform STS (Semantic Textual Similarity) on unsupervised dataset using deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, unsupervised-learning, similarity

How do you implement STS(Semantic Textual Similarity) on an unlabelled dataset? The dataset column contains `Unique_id`, `text1` (contains paragraph), and `text2` (contains paragraph).

Ex: Column representation:  Unique_id   |    Text1    |     Text2

**Unique_id** 0

`Text1` public show for Reynolds suspension of his coaching licence. portrait Sir Joshua Reynolds portrait of omai will get a public airing following fears it would stay hidden because of an export wrangle.

`Text2` then requested to do so by Spain's anti-violence commission. The fine was far less than the expected amount of about Â£22 000 or even the suspension of his coaching license.

**Unique_id** 1

`Text1` Groening. Gervais has already begun writing the script but is keeping its subject matter a closely guarded secret. he will also write a part for himself in the episode. I've got the rough idea but this is the most intimidating project of my career.

`Text2` Philadelphia said they found insufficient evidence to support the woman s allegations regarding an alleged incident in January 2004. The woman reported the allegations to Canadian authorities last month. Cosby s lawyer Walter m Phillips jr said the comedian was pleased with the decision.

In the above problem, I've to compare two paragraphs of texts i.e. `Text1` & `Text2`, and then I've to compare semantic similarity between two texts. If they are semantically similar then it will print '1' if not then '0'

Any reference implementation link or any suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a pretrained embedder and look for distances between the embeddings.
There's [LASER](https://engineering.fb.com/ai-research/laser-multilingual-sentence-embeddings/) from Facebook. [This](https://pypi.org/project/laserembeddings/) is an unofficial `pypi` package, it replaces some of the internal tools used for tokenization and BPE encodings. I have used it extensively and it works just fine. It encodes your text as a 1024-element numerical vector. Then you can just calculate distance metric between embeddings i.e. Euclidean.

Comment: In the above problem, I've to compare two paragraphs texts i.e. Text1 & Text2 and then I've to compare semantic similarity between two texts. If they are semantically similar then it will print '1' if not then '0'.

Comment: As you want to do it in unsupervised way, you'd eventually need to set some threshold manually on metric.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google universal sentence encoder, check out the Colab version of UC and just replace the example query in there with your two queries and it will give the similarity score between any two sentences. It is the best for calculating semantic text similarity.